# Remove "In" from inproceedings entries using makebst file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, custom-bib

I have made a custom `.bst` file using `makebst`, but I can't remove the "In" before the `booktitle` in `inproceedings` entries. That is, right now my entries read:

> ..."title." In *Proceedings of Conference,* ...

but I would like them to read:

> ..."title." *Proceedings of Conference,* ...

Is there a way to edit this in the `.dbj` file, or in my `.bst` file directly?

Comment: Do you still have the `.dbj` file produced by the `makebst` utility?

Comment: Can you upload you current branch?

Comment: Mico - I do have the .dbj file

Comment: Marco - I'm not sure what you mean by branch.

Answer (score 5):

In your .bst file there should be the following function:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.in}

{ "in" }
```

Replace it with:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.in}

{ "" }
```

This will remove the "in" in the reference for inproceedings entries.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I am using Overleaf. I couldnt find .bst file. How can i get rid of "In".

Comment: @CODError [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: This did not work for me!